# Where are all the cats in Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

You have to use cats to switch between Catwoman and Batman in the main story, but I've seen only seen one group of cats, the ones right next to Catwoman's apartment. It's a hassle to fly back there whenever I want to switch. The game says that there are multiple groups of them, but I can't find more. Where are all of the other cats?

Comment: Aw, now it makes sense out of context without the tag in the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the cat locations in Arkham City:

[image: main]

A close-up:

[image: close-up]

Comment: Notice how they're on the minimap...

Answer (score 1):

There's one on the shore near the Joker's side of town.  They should be visible on your minimap with a cat icon

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can't see them on the minimap. A picture would be a great help.

Comment: Sorry, I got distracted at work.  Looks like Mehper got you straightened out though.